# Java SDK Mismatch

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere, java-5

I have an old WebSphere app that I'm trying to compile with Java 1.5.  I'm working in in IntelliJ on Windows 10.  In my Project Settings I have the Project SDK set as:

```
1.5 (java version "1.5.0_22")
```

I also have 1.8 available, but it's definitely not what's selected in the Project SDK.

When I do a rebuild on my project I see:

```
Information:javac 1.8.0_152-release was used to compile java sources
```

It seems to build just fine, but when I try to visit my local website I see:

```
Error 500: (PathToMYServletGoesHere) bad major version at offset=6
```

I understand that this is error is related to a version mismatch.

Thanks

Comment: Just somehow specify target for your compilation like `javac -target 1.5 <source files>.`. Are you using Maven to build or just IntelliJ project? Either set target in the `pom.xml` or in IntelliJ settings - Java compiler -> project bytecode (dont have IntelliJ at hand so naming might be little different ;-) )